# Is it possible to check if host filter connection by mac address

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nmap

I've got a task to got restrict the users by Mac addresses of it's hardware, that should be routers. I want to grant firewall restriction by mac address and see if it possible to understand via nmap program.

Thanks in any advance !

Comment: This is a very poor security feature that can lead you to believe you are protected, but you simply are not protected. It is unbelievably simple to spoof a MAC address, and hosts broadcast their MAC addresses all the time, so it is a simple matter to see what the MAC address of a valid host is and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to block ports for a specific MAC address on a firewall? If yes, on your router page, you should have a block services feature. You can do it by IP address. NMAP shows what ports are open on a server/device.

If you want to block a MAC address, use the Access Control. Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes,  I need to block ports 80 for specified devices On my Linux server. But from nmap how it is possible to check whether it blocks by mac or by IP address?

Comment: Well, you could use Wireshark to analyse packets. That might help.  I do use Wireshark but never tried something like that. I don't think you can use NMAP to see if something is blocked by MAC or IP address. Do you want to actually check if the device has port 80 blocked?

Comment: It's blocked, I can't get to the Internet. I want to  get reason of block. Thanks I'll check Wireshark, wondering it is available for Debian